# Different sphere geometry with classic polygons vs pathtraced

Tags: opengl, glsl

[image]

This screenshot is from my OpenGL program. You can see two spheres on top of each other: The blueish earth sphere and a slightly bigger overlaid transparent red sphere. bigger red sphere was rendered with a standard polygon sphere. The smaller one was rendered via pathtracing. Both should be the same size (same radius!), but are apparently not - why?

The Polygon rendering is pretty trivial and probably the correct one. For pathtracing, I render a full screen rect. In the fragment shader, I use the camera position as the ray start. For ray direction, I use this snippet:

```
vec3 ray_direction = (inverse_projection * vec4(unorm_to_snorm(gl_FragCoord.xy/fb_size), 1.0, 1.0)).xyz;
```

with `inverse_projection` being `inverse(projection * view)`

And from there, it's really just a standard ray-sphere intersection test. I used two different code fragments I found on the net, but both yielded the same results. So I assume something is wrong with my ray direction maybe? But that's just a guess. I've seen that being used quite a lot. Any ideas?

btw, technically this isn't pathtracing I guess, as a ray-sphere can be calculated in one go without iteration. Not sure if that's still the correct term to use.

here's the vertex shader for the polygon sphere:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
uniform float planet_radius;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(planet_radius * position, 1.0);
}
```

and here's the fragment shader for the pathtraced sphere (simplified):

```
#version 460 core
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform float planet_radius;
uniform mat4 inverse_projection;
uniform vec2 fb_size;

float hit_sphere(vec3 center, float radius, vec3 rayOrigin, vec3 rayDir){
    vec3 oc = rayOrigin - center;
    float a = dot(rayDir, rayDir);
    float b = 2.0 * dot(oc, rayDir);
    float c = dot(oc,oc) - radius*radius;
    float discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;
    if(discriminant < 0){
        return -1.0;
    }
    else{
        return (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0*a);
    }
}

void main()
{
    vec3 ray_direction = (inverse_projection * vec4(unorm_to_snorm(gl_FragCoord.xy/fb_size), 1.0, 1.0)).xyz;
    vec3 ray_origin = cam_pos;
    vec3 planet_center = vec3(0);
    float dist_to_planet = hit_sphere(planet_center, planet_radius, ray_origin, ray_direction);
    vec3 hit_pos = ray_origin + dist_to_planet * ray_direction;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
    if(dist_to_planet > 0)
    {
        color = vec3(1.0);
    }
    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}     #version 460 core
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform float planet_radius;
uniform mat4 inverse_projection;
uniform vec2 fb_size;

float hit_sphere(vec3 center, float radius, vec3 rayOrigin, vec3 rayDir){
    vec3 oc = rayOrigin - center;
    float a = dot(rayDir, rayDir);
    float b = 2.0 * dot(oc, rayDir);
    float c = dot(oc,oc) - radius*radius;
    float discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;
    if(discriminant < 0){
        return -1.0;
    }
    else{
        return (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0*a);
    }
}

void main()
{
    vec3 ray_direction = (inverse_projection * vec4(unorm_to_snorm(gl_FragCoord.xy/fb_size), 1.0, 1.0)).xyz;
    vec3 ray_origin = cam_pos;
    vec3 planet_center = vec3(0);
    float dist_to_planet = hit_sphere(planet_center, planet_radius, ray_origin, ray_direction);
    vec3 hit_pos = ray_origin + dist_to_planet * ray_direction;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
    if(dist_to_planet > 0)
    {
        color = vec3(1.0);
    }
    FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

another edit: Pathtracing done in CPU is correct. Just on GPU it seems to be misaligned. So the inverse matrix in particular should be correct.

Comment: Can't help unless you provide your sphere-mesh vertex data

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov The polygon sphere is just a sphere with radius 1 exported from cinema 4d. I manually confirmed that it's actually of radius 1.0. This vertex data is multiplied in the vertex shader with the radius of 4.0, which is the same radius used in the pathtracing fragment shader.

Comment: Please, provide both the shaders atleast. It's really no help to debug "your words" instead of the actual code.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov alright, edited in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the ray direction is not taking the camera position into account. So for `ray_direction` you likely want to subtract the `cam_pos`.